# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline Blocking Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Can I block the run of my current job if the job B is currently running?
There is a plugin for Jenkins job (Blocking Job) to do this but I'm not sure how to do this in Pipeline using Jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you use lockable resources https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/

Job B grabs the lock, and Job A cannot run untill the lock is freed and it can grab it

```
 stage("Run Post-Deployment Test") {
     options {
         lock(resource: "deploy-env")
     }
```

This will take the "deploy-env" lock untill the end of the stage. Meaning if another deploy tried to happen it couldnt grab the lock untill the tests stage had finished.

Note if a lock doesnt exist Jenkins will create it for you.